# PDO Class is not working returns a blank page when I try to run it?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I've created an email class that will add users to a mysql database.
then I've created  two methods, the first is private static so I can access it within the second method which is public static, when run this class displays a blank page?
What could be the cause of the blank page?

```
class Email {
private static function DATABASE() {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=emails", 'bjw123nasd4441', 'hj12j2kJKj11s');
    return $dbh;
}
public static function addemail($email) {
    $sqldata = array('email' => $email);
        $stat = Email::DATABASE();
    $stat->prepare("INSERT INTO tasklist (email) VALUES (:email)");
    $stat->execute($sqldata);
    }
}

Email::addemail('foo@bar.com');
```

I get this error with PHP Display Errors..

Call to undefined method PDO::execute()

Comment: You didn't printout here anything, why do expect to see something not blank?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you try to directly call `pdo->execute()`, that won't work. try this:

```
$stat = self::DATABASE();
$query = $stat->prepare("INSERT INTO tasklist (email) VALUES (:email)");
$query->execute($sqldata);
```

and you should also just use one pdo instance:

```
class Email {

    private static $dbh = null;

    private static function DATABASE() {
        if(is_null(self::$dbh))
            self::$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=emails", 'bjw123nasd4441', 'hj12j2kJKj11s');
        return self::$dbh;
    }

    //...

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you receive an FATAL error on this line:

```
$stat = Task::DATABASE();
```

Task does not exist? This should be `Email::DATABASE();`.

I assume you are not showing your errors too, you could attempt setting the following at the top of your script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

This should fix your white screen with an clear error.

**Sidenote(s)**

1. You instantiate a new database connection on each email you want to add.
2. I believe an class Email shouldn't be in charge of your database connection.

Comment: I fixed the mistake and it still seams to be causing an error? Are the methods correct?

Comment: @Ian Wood I used the self keyword and it still displays a blank page?